# Embedding binary files within HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, base64, embed

I need to embed binary files(e.g., Word documents, PPT etc) within HTML files. Currently, I'm converting the files into base64 format and including the base64 encoded content in the HTML file. This HTML file will be submitted to another web application, which will then read the contents(base64 encoded files) and save the contents to the filesystem. Is there a better way of embedding files within HTML files?

ok..Here's the reason why I need to embed them..Application A lets users download files as HTML files with embedded content. Users can just open this HTML file, which will automatically upload the embedded content into Application B. I know it sounds like a crazy requirement, but this is what I need to build..

Comment: didn't understand why you want it. but `HTML` can have only text.

Comment: you can zip them all up and embed the zip as a dataURL or json/js string. all in all, jszip and base64 dataURLs as anchor hrefs are probably your best bet because they can be downloaded by users without JS, or unpacked with JS and dished out one at a time.

Comment: are you trying to show the docs or just have a reference to it to send to next request?

Comment: I'm not displaying the documents in the UI..I'm just trying to get the files uploaded into the target application - 'Application B'.